# Heroku ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template wordclouds/index, application/index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So, I am trying to deploy my Rails app to Heroku. The deploy succeeds just fine but then when I navigate to the Heroku url, I see the Rails standard "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message.

I checked the Heroku logs, and at the top of the stack trace I see:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template wordclouds/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2015-11-07T19:17:23.924582+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
```

I definitely have a working root route, which is `wordclouds#index`. This route and index view render perfectly fine in development, on my local machine. What is different on Heroku?

Also, all the source code of my app is [on GitHub](https://github.com/awanninger/wordcloud-ninja).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a file "index.html.erb" into the folder app/views/wordclouds

Comment: Thanks Ted, but if you look at my code, I already have that file, in that directory, and the route exists.

Comment: sorry about that... I was trying to click through the github interface when I should have pulled it. so much to learn.Thank you for introducing me to a git submodule!

Comment: No problem Ted! Git submodules can cause a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that `app/views/wordclouds` had been initialized as a git submodule, and Heroku just didn't like that. Once I removed the submodule, Heroku worked fine.